# Handle different form tabs as one form

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form divided in different tabs. These are handled by ui-router:

```js
$stateProvider.state('articledetail', {
  url: '/articledetail/:article',
  templateUrl: '/articledetail/articleDetail.html',
  controller: 'articleDetailController',
  controllerAs: 'vm'
})
.state('articledetail.tab1', {
  url: '/tab1',
  templateUrl: '/articledetail/tab1.html'
})
.state('articledetail.tab2', {
  url: '/tab2',
  templateUrl: '/articledetail/tab2.html'
})
.state('articledetail.tab3', {
  url: '/tab3',
  templateUrl: '/articledetail/tab3.html'
})
.state('articledetail.tab4', {
  url: '/tab4',
  templateUrl: '/articledetail/tab4.html'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal" name="editForm" novalidate>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" ng-class="{active: vm.$state.current.name == 'articledetail.tab1'}"><a ui-sref="articledetail.tab1" aria-controls="tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Algemene info</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" ng-class="{active: vm.$state.current.name == 'articledetail.tab2'}"><a ui-sref="articledetail.tab2" aria-controls="tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Info 2</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" ng-class="{active: vm.$state.current.name == 'articledetail.tab3'}"><a ui-sref="articledetail.tab3" aria-controls="tab3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Info 3</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" ng-class="{active: vm.$state.current.name == 'articledetail.tab41'}"><a ui-sref="articledetail.tab4" aria-controls="tab4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Info 4</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content col-xs-7">
    <div ui-view></div>
    <br />

    <div class="col-xs-7">
      <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-disabled="editForm.$invalid" ng-click="vm.test(editForm)">Artikelgegevens aanpassen</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

In my controller method after the click event, editForm only contains the fields of the tab which is displayed, not the fields from the other tabs. I'd like however, to have one submit button to process ALL fields from the different tabs.

Is there a (simple) way to achieve this?

EDIT:
This is my routing now:

```
    $stateProvider.state('articledetail', {
        url: '/articledetail/:article',
        templateUrl: '/articledetail/articleDetail.html',
        controller: 'articleDetailController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        views: {
            'tab1': {
                templateUrl: '/articledetail/tab1.html'
            },
            'tab2': {
                templateUrl: '/articledetail/tab2.html'
            },
            'tab3': {
                templateUrl: '/articledetail/tab3.html'
            },
            'tab4': {
                templateUrl: '/articledetail/tab4.html'
            }
        }
        });
```

Comment: then you should have all the form element should be present on DOM while posting form, currently you are showing each view at that time using `ui-view`

Comment: But what's the easiest way to achieve that?

Comment: load all the view at same time..only show and hide them on basis of click of tab

Comment: So basically the only thing I can do is to remove this whole routing system and put everything on one page?

Comment: Or use sessionStorage to save all and ajax a post on the final submit

Comment: the your tab routing state will be removed and all the view will included to `articledetail` state using `views: {}`

Comment: So how would views: {} look like? I can't get it to work by adding the 4 tabs...

Comment: I've added my current routing in the OP

Answer (score 0):

ok I think I can see what you are trying to achieve.
But before I go into it, having a look at your initial solution, you should consider using `ui-sref-active="active"` insead of `ng-class`.

Anyway, the current problem.
You wish to have a model shared between multiple views, but one submit button that handles it all.
If you wish to use views then you should use a service to hold your model.
Otherwise, taking your first state setup you are able to share the controller for the parent state with the child states.

I have set up a codepen for you to look at.

http://codepen.io/r3plica/pen/OVgRmV